# Pots in an old Tek 2205 Scope change when wiggled

Tags: oscilloscope

I have a Tek 2205 scope I picked up from Ebay. Thing is fully functional except I had to replace the pot for the trace rotation. I'm going through a calibration procedure.

I've cleaned all the pots with electronics cleaner and DeOxit which helped their "noisiness", however the horizontal and vertical position controls are still finicky, in that if I just wiggle the control (not turn it, but wiggle it) the position changes.

Is this simply a condition of the pots being 40+ years old and need replacement? The front panel board looks fine and doesn't have any bad solder joints or broken traces, and this happens with all 3 position controls.

Comment: Well, you had to replace one pot, and all the other pots are the same age ...  seems like a reasonable debugging step to me.

Comment: Yeah they probably need replaced.  If this was a car sitting for 40+ years, would not more than a few things need replaced?

Comment: @Scott Seidman While that's true, the other pot was physically broken.

Comment: Probably from a user wiggling it too hard ;-)